# URL Routing in ASP.Net webforms running under the Classic .NET AppPool

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-routing

Does anybody knows if it is possible to make URL routing in a ASP.Net webforms website that is running under the Classic .NET AppPool.

I've tried a few things here, but it just works when I switch from Classic AppPool to Default AppPool.

** the web site MUST run under Classic AppPool.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite 2 Module is capable of URL Rewriting / URL Rewriting regardless whether the application pool runs under the classic or integrated pipeline mode.

(For your curiosity: just tested it)

Comment: Tks, Ive seen something about URL Rewriting, but Id like to try using only .Net framework, to keep things simpler. Anyway, tks a lot..

Comment: I don't understand your point. Give me one valid reason, why you don't want to use an official nice and clean way to rewrite/redirect urls? http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you. Would you mind upvoting my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .net 3.5 routing .This is great sample
https://web.archive.org/web/20201205221404/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx

Comment: Tks, Ive done it already but it doesnt work under Classic AppPool